# How to draw square pixel with different colors using SWT application

Tags: java, swt, pixel

I am working on a fluid simulation application using SWT and want to draw the final calculated density of fluid back to UI. Now I am thinking about using SWT canvas and GC, but GC seems only for drawing shapes and lines, without the ability to draw colored pixels

There are many simulation app in the website but none is implemented by SWT. Below is the expected result for this application:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use GC.[drawPoint](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fgraphics%2FGC.html) to draw a single pixel, the colour will be that set with GC.[setForeground](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fgraphics%2FGC.html).

Answer (score 2):

Jonah's answer is the way to do it if you want to draw everything yourself.

I'm just posting this as an alternative:

There's a library called ["JHC (Java Heat Map Control)"](https://github.com/prasser/jhc) that you could use to draw your data.

It would look something like this:

[image]

The data is provided in the form of an `int[][]`.

```
// Define scales
JHCScale<String> xScale = new JHCScale.String(new String[] { "X1", "X2", "X3" });
JHCScale<String> yScale = new JHCScale.String(new String[] { "Y1", "Y2", "Y3" });

// Configure
JHCLayout layout = new JHCLayout(false, 20, true, 20);
JHCConfiguration config = new JHCConfiguration("x-label", "y-label", 
                                               JHCGradient.GRADIENT_HEAT, layout);

// Create array
int[][] array = {{0,1,0}, {1,2,1}, {0,1,0}};

// Create data object
JHCData data = JHCData.create(array, Orientation.ROW, xScale, yScale);

// Create JHC widget
JHC jhc = new JHC(shell, SWT.NONE);
jhc.setData(data, config);
```

Comment: I like this answer, it may very well solve the underlying problem OP had, +1